# Sidebar ocultacion

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

tengo un main en bootstrap 5 que quiero que pase a ocupar todo el ancho de la pantalla cuando oculto la sidebar.

```
<main id="mainElement" class="col-md-12 ms-sm-auto col-lg-12 px-md-4">
```

El js que estoy usando para ocultar la sidebar me la oculta correctamente pero no me cambia las clases del main, es el siguiente:

```
function toggleSidebar() {
var sidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");
var toggleIcon = document.getElementById("toggleIcon");
var mainElement = document.getElementById("mainElement");

if (sidebar.style.display === "none" || sidebar.style.display === "") {
  sidebar.style.display = "block";
  toggleIcon.innerHTML = "<<";
  // Remueve la clase actual
  mainElement.classList.remove("col-md-9");
  mainElement.classList.remove("col-lg-10");
  

  // Agrega la nueva clase
  mainElement.classList.add("col-md-12");
  mainElement.classList.add("col-lg-12");
} else {
  sidebar.style.display = "none";
  toggleIcon.innerHTML = ">>";
  // Remueve la clase actual
  mainElement.classList.remove("col-md-12");
  mainElement.classList.remove("col-lg-12");

  // Agrega la nueva clase
  mainElement.classList.add("col-md-9");
  mainElement.classList.add("col-lg-10");
}
```

};

Le estoy dando vueltas pero no entiendo porque no me cambia la clase, alguna idea de que puede ser?

Saludos!

Comment: ¿Es Bootstrap? Y si lo es, ¿qué versión? No olvides ponerlo en las etiquetas de ser así.

Comment: Puedes además mostrar un [repro] ejecutable en la pregunta misma, a través del botón que indica `<>`.

Comment: A ocupar toda la pantalla te referis al ancho supongo

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionando utilizando el siguiente js para modificar la class:

```
mainElement.className = "col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4"
```

Supongo que hay una forma mas eficiente pero de momento esto cumple con lo que estaba buscando.